# Has the Doctor ever communicated telepathically with this character before?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord, psychic

In 'Spyfall' (the first episode of series 12) the Doctor comes across a man who is subsequently revealed to be

> the Master

In the subsequent episode (part 2) they communicate telepathically. Time Lords being psychic is [apparently not new](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126044/are-time-lords-psychic) although I can't recall seeing the Doctor communicating telepathically before.

Their conversation indicates that this isn't a new thing for them.

> **Doctor:** He's not so far. I can sense him. Contact.
>   **Character:** Contact. Old school.
>   **Doctor:** You're not the only one who can do classic.

So have they done telepathy before? If so, what was the episode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Time Lords psychic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/126044/31394) (Note: this is not an automatic "possible duplicate" comment, but a genuine question as to whether you think it's resolved over there.)

Comment: Ah, now I see you've actually linked that question already. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in The Deadly Assassin:

> Well, don't you see what he's done? We Time Lords are telepathic. That's simply a brain storage system. He intercepted its forecast that the President was to be assassinated and beamed it into my mind.

The quotation being the Doctor, talking about the Master

Comment: Was that the Master speaking?

Comment: That was the Doctor, talking about the Master.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [TARDIS Wikia page](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Telepathic_contact) on "telepathic contact", **yes**, in the audio story ["The Missing Link"](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Missing_Link_(audio_story)):

> Telepathic contact was a Time Lord ability to form a telepathic link between multiple minds for high-speed conversations and decision-making. The ability was used by different incarnations of the Doctor <sup>(TV: The Three Doctors, The Five Doctors)</sup> or two versions of the same incarnation from different points in time. <sup>(AUDIO: The Wrong Doctors)</sup> It was also possible between two different Time Lords <sup>(AUDIO: The Apocalypse Element, The Missing Link, TV: The End of Time, Spyfall)</sup> or three <sup>(AUDIO: Intervention Earth)</sup> as well as between a Time Lord and a human <sup>(AUDIO: Love and War, TV: The Girl in the Fireplace, The Lodger)</sup>

Among the stories mentioned for telepathic contact between two different Time Lords, "The Missing Link" ([see reviews](https://thetimescales.com/Story/story.php?audioid=3180)) is one about the Doctor and the Master, so presumably those two use telepathic contact together. (Full disclosure: I haven't actually listened to this story.)

Comment: The Brain of Morbius as well, although that may not count, as they use a machine to facilitate the connection